# Add different class depending on state

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I have a `div` that needs some kind of `background-color`. The color depends on the value in the `div` which can be either negative, zero, or positive.

For example:

```
<div className={`colors ${value > 0 ? "green" : ""}`}>{value}</div>
```

With SCSS:

```
.colors {
    padding: 10px;

    &.green {
        background-color: green;
    }
 }
```

Would make the `background-color` green if the `value` is above 0. But how can I transform this so that if the `value` is zero then a `neutral` class with `background-color` grey is added, and a red class with `background-color` red if negative.

Comment: The ternary inside `${...}` would look like `${value > 0 ? "green" : value < 0 ? "red" : "gray"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close there with the ternary; you can easily solve this by implementing nested ternary statements inside your template. Let's say you have three CSS classes: `green` for positive, `red` for negative, and `neutral` for 0.

We can create a nested ternary to match all operations, something like this:

```js
value > 0
  ? "green" // positive, make it green
  : value < 0
    ? "red" // negative, it's red
    : "neutral" // it's neither positive nor negative; it's 0; make it neutral
```

In your JSX that'd look something like:

```
<div className={`colors {
  value > 0
  ? "green"
  : value < 0
    ? "red"
    : "neutral"
}`>{value}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try this:

```
const bgColor = new Map([
  [false, "negative"],
  [true, "positive"],
  [0, "neutral"],
]);

<div className={`colors ${bgColor.get(value)}`}>{value}</>
```

Comment: In maps, negative (number) values don't equate to `false`, neither do positive values map to true. If `value` was either negative or positive the map would return `undefined`.